# Ajax running a specific function

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, directory

I have 7 folders, within these folders hold a dozen more folders. These structures will change slightly over time. Within these subfolders are photos (which is that not that relevant right now).

I want to be able to create an auto way of loading these folders as menus.
my plan was to click one of the seven menus, then in another div tag load the folder names as a menu list. I'm a complete noob and got stuck in doing this.

I have written this below. This is the HTML side.

```
  <div class="coffee-span-3 subgrid-column-5">
        <p class="paragraph material_left_menu_header_para"><span class="Small_Header_Text">Marine Vinyls</span></p>
           <a class="link-text material_link_container" href="#"id="CTP Marine Vinyls"><span class="text-link-text-1">CTP Marine Vinyls</span>
           <a class="link-text material_link_container" href="#"id="Nautolex Vinyls"><span class="text-link-text-1">Nautolex Vinyls</span>

        <p class="paragraph material_left_menu_header_para"><span class="Small_Header_Text">Fabrics</span></p>
           <a class="link-text material_link_container" href="#"id="Auga"><span class="text-link-text-1">Auga</span>
           <a class="link-text material_link_container" href="#"id="Covertex"><span class="text-link-text-1">Covertex</span>

        <p class="paragraph material_left_menu_header_para"><span class="Small_Header_Text">Acrylics</span></p>
           <a class="link-text material_link_container" href="#"id="Topgun"><span class="text-link-text-1">Topgun</span>
           <a class="link-text material_link_container" href="#"id="Odyssey"><span class="text-link-text-1">Odyssey</span>
           <a class="link-text material_link_container" href="#" id="Acrylic Canvas"><span class="text-link-text-1">Acrylic Canvas</span>



    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".link-text").click(function(){
                var $contentPanelId = jQuery(this).attr("id");
                var $boopboop = ("Images/Pictures/materials/" + $contentPanelId + "/");

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',

                    url: 'php_functions.php?name=$boopboop',

                    success: function(path) 
                    {
                         $( '#somthing' ).append( path );
                    }
                }); 
       });
    });
    </script>

    <div id="somthing"> </div>

  </div>
```

I have it looking at a php script to gather the directory list. called php_functions.

```
function collect_dir_create_link ($path_name) 
{ 
    $dir_open = opendir($path_name);

    while(false !== ($filename = readdir($dir_open))){
        if($filename != "." && $filename != ".."){
            $link = "<a href='./$filename'> $filename </a><br />";
            echo $link;
        }
    }

    closedir($dir_open);
}; 


$name = $_GET['name'];
if(isset($name))
{
  collect_dir_create_link($name);
}
```

The end product being, I want to have to manually create 80 pages or so. I haven't got to automating each page for each new link created with the photos. one step at a time.

For now to get it to load the links as lists would be amazing.
Any help will be so appreciated. I just cant get this to work.

Comment: If it were me, id use something like http://www.directorylister.com/, no need to re-invent the wheel here, unless you just relly want to roll your own ;)

Comment: Ay thank you for the reply. This is awesome, not quite what im looking for though.  I'm writing this for a friend and it needs to be quite bespoke. Right now i'm stuck on getting the Var $boopboop sending across the filepath and not just echo $boopboop. Also this is a lot of fun working out the puzzles. Apologies, first time writing a question, should have been more to the point.